# Changing IP for a scraping script

Tags: python, proxy, ip, web-scraping, hide

I am trying to a website, but my IP has been banned after a while. I have tried using Tor proxy, but it's unstable and slow. Therefor I think the best solution might be a standard proxy that would be obfuscating it's IP say once per 12 hours. Or do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: How about getting permission from the site you're trying to scrape instead of trying to sneak your way past their block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP spoofing is useless since the server response would be delivered to some undesired address. You'll either have to ask the site owner or setup something like a botnet which won't be easy nor cheap.